# Specify SMB 3.0 in /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

TL;DR: What is the syntax to mount a CIFS share via SMB3 in /etc/fstab?

Previously, I had this working in my /etc/fstab:

```
//192.168.1.100/Movies /mnt/Media cifs credentials=/home/syn/.smbcred,uid=111,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

But after some bug with the server, I now need to specify the SMB version when mounting.  I am able to do this via mount:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.100/Movies /mnt/Media -o vers=3.0,user=plex,uid=111,gid=1000,pass=PASSWORD
```

But I cannot seem to specify the version in fstab and get it to work.  Any ideas?

Similar [thread here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855708/mounting-window-shares-requires-vers-3-0-to-mount-what-about-fstab), but unanswered.

Comment: See the samba config file:https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html   SMB3 is the default by the way unless you specify otherwise and it will use a lower version when the client asks for it.

Comment: If you mount shares from a modern version of Windows, do not use vers=1.0. This version of SMB protocol is deprecated, unefficient and gives you a very bad performance. Use vers=3.0 as minimum and if doesn’t work, specify sec=ntlmv2 It’s another common issue that some people use sec=ntlm instead of sec=ntlmv2. Ntlmv1 is an insecure authentication method and it’s disabled by security updates on Windows or Windows Server which hosts the share. So you probably get a permission/authentication related error when try to mount the share with sec=ntlm Cheers

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same problem which was also due to an upgrade to one of my institute’s servers. I managed to mount the share by adding the vers=3.0 option to fstab **without the -o argument**.

```
//192.168.1.100/Movies /mnt/Media cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/syn/.smbcred,uid=111,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Comment: While this post was a while ago and I had figured out the syntax, I forgot to update the post.  Thank you, kmdouglass, for posting.

Here is my working syntax for mounting a CIFS 3 hosted on FreeNAS to Ubuntu:

//192.168.1.1/Media  /mnt/Media  cifs credentials=/home/me/.smbcred,uid=100,gid=1000,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8 0 0

Edit based on your local environment.  **-o is not needed in /etc/fstab**

Comment: little sad this has been viewed 68,000 times and you've only gotten 15 ^. Anyway, thanks for the concise answer! exactly what i needed after upgrading kernal to 5.15 on centos 7.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue after installing Ubuntu 18.04. Package cifs-utils now uses SMB 2.1 or greater and I needed to use version 1.

In /etc/fstab add vers=n.n right after your credentials file like here:

```
//192.168.1.144/video /media/nas/ cifs auto,credentials=/.smbcredentials_3,vers=1.0,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```